# Multiplying Different Data Types in an Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, operators

I am receiving an error "Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'decimal[]'", as I am attempting to multiply two values with different data types (one being a value located in an array). My question is how am I able to multiple numberOfMinutes * perMinuteRate in my code below?  My variable is called total, which I declared a double data type (although may be incorrect).

I tried changing data types and played with formatting (like ToString), but I am not sure what to do.  I also tried to google the answer with no success.

I am by no means a professional programmer; I'm not in school. I'm a data analyst who is learning to program.

Here is my code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     int[] areaCodes = { 262, 414, 608, 715, 815, 920 };
     decimal[] perMinuteRate = { .07m, .1m, .05m, .16m, .24m, .14m };
     int numberOfMinutes;
     int userAreaCode;
     string inputString = "1";

     while (inputString != "0")
     {
        int x;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the area code for your call (or 1 to end):");
        inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        userAreaCode = Convert.ToInt32(inputString);

        Console.WriteLine("How many minutes will your call last?");
        inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        numberOfMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(inputString);

        for (x = 0; x < areaCodes.Length; x++)
        {
           if (userAreaCode == areaCodes[x])
           {
              ***double total = numberOfMinutes * perMinuteRate;***
              Console.WriteLine("You call to {0} will cost {1} per minute for a total of {2}.", areaCodes[x], perMinuteRate[x].ToString("C"), total.ToString("C"));
              x = areaCodes.Length;
           }
        }

        if (x != areaCodes.Length)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry; we don't cover that area.");
           inputString = "1";
        }
        else
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Thanks for being our customer.");
           inputString = "0";
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
     }
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you meant `perMinuteRate[x]`

Comment: `***double total = numberOfMinutes * perMinuteRate;***` what is this code meant to signify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
double total = numberOfMinutes * perMinuteRate;
```

to

```
double total = (double)(numberOfMinutes * perMinuteRate[x]);
```

The same way you index into `perMinuteRate` in the line directly below.

The expression `[int] * [decimal]` will result in a decimal, and the cast `(double)` will convert it to a double

To avoid loss of precision, change it to:

```
decimal total = numberOfMinutes * perMinuteRate[x];
```

Comment: When dealing with these types of implicit conversions (int*decimal) its best to leave the result in the widest format, in this case a `decimal`, I'd at least note that converting to a `double` is a loss-of-precision operation, and real value can be lost in the case of money. There isn't a good reason to use `double` over `decimal` here.

Comment: Mathias & Ron, thanks for your help and the explanation.  This worked "decimal total = numberOfMinutes * perMinuteRate[x];"  .  I apologize for apparently asking a bad question.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for the encouragement! I was considering not posting to this site again since I am not a pro yet, but I will--thanks to your kind words.  I'll try to be more specific & have harder questions next time.